# My very small company has reached the point of needing a VCS. I'm trying to plan our actual version control strategy first

Tags: version-control, branch, trunk

First and foremost, please excuse my writing: I'm a programmer fresh out of college with minimal professional experience. If anything is unclear, please bring it up and I'll do my best to clarify.

I'm looking forward to using a VCS to help us to organize everything. Keeping track of bug fixes, development of new features, merging, and development of new editions should simplified, clarified, and made much easier.

This is how we plan to use version control (given my fledgling understanding of VCSs):

For the sake of a clear example, we'll call our current and released version of the software V1 and in-development next version V2.

- We plan to start with V1 as the trunk of our tree.
- A branch will be made for development of V2. This branch will never be merged back in, thus it is effectively the new trunk for V2.
- Branches would be split off of this new trunk for development of new features for V2 and merged back in when they are complete.
- Should bug fixes be needed for V1, branches would be made off of the V1 trunk, completed, and merged back into the V1 trunk. V2 development would need to pause as the V2 trunk updates from changed V1 trunk, then all V2 branches update from the newly changed V2 trunk. Then various V2 branches could resume development.
- When enough features have been branched off of the V2 trunk, completed, and merged back in, eventually it will be time to release V2 and start on V3. V3 will branch off of V2 and never merge back in (like V2 did from V1), and the process begins again.

Is this a reasonable model? Will it be effective? Is it likely to develop issues over time due to my uneducated attempt at planning?

Please let me know anything else I can provide to help you to help me. Thank you!

Comment: The doc on SVN you may want to read is SVNBook http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/index.html

Comment: As already observed this question is off topic, but before it gets removed... I would recommend Mercurial (I'm just going to call it Hg from now on). We used to use SVN and moved to Hg and merging and branched development is much less traumatic in Hg. It is perfectly stable, well documented, and has been around for years at this point. I always recommend a look at this tutorial which covers a bit about the differences between the two: http://hginit.com/index.html. If you're on Windows TortoiseHg is a good client for it. I think Hg is probably the middle ground between SVN and Git.

Comment: Look at [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org): it has integrated bug tracker, wiki and project documentation, and, while being a DVCS, with default settings it mimics the behaviour of a centralized VCS using its "autosync" feature. It's self-hosting in that it can be run on any supported platform as a daemon/service w/o any additional fuss.

Comment: One possible downside of Fossil is that it does not have any "go-to" desktop GUI solution (while several 3rd-party front-ends to it do exist) so while its self-hosting web UI covers 90% of the needs, committing changes, switching branches and pushing/fetching are done via its command-line.